# Is there a way to manually set the ApplicationSession network timeout for Android Chromecasting?

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm sending a MediaProtocolMessageStream.loadMedia command to my receiver.  After a few seconds my session ends with a "network I/O timeout" with channel=SessionError.CATEGORY_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL and code=SessionError.CODE_TIMEOUT.  This only happens for longer videos in the range of over 200 minutes so I'm assuming there's a legitimate timeout going on.  Is there anyway to tweak the timeout time in a session so I can load larger movies?  I see there's a final DEFAULT_TIMEOUT in the underlying NetworkRequest, but I have no way of accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout value cannot be adjusted by application. It would help us to understand what is causing the timeout in your case. Timeout happens when either the sender does not reply to the receiver's ping requests in a timely manner, or when the sender has not received a ping from the receiver for a certain length of time. It *might* be the case that the media you are trying to load is tying up the CPU on the receiver so that it can't send its ping request to the sender. Do you see anything in the sender's log similar to "timeout waiting for ping" or so?

Comment: I don't see any internal logging on my sender.  The only evidence is that my ApplicationSession.Listener() onSessionEnded is fired with the previously mentioned error codes.  I can't find any error logs on my receiver either.  I just see a LOAD received and a STATUS sent. Would be great if I could get some diagnostics on the receiver or some more logging on either end.

Comment: Would you please contact me on the chromecast-updates mailing list? Once we resolve that there (I need some more info from you), we can report back here about our findings.

Comment: How can I access the list?

Comment: please send an email to chromecast-updates@google.com

Comment: Turns out the Android Chromecast code uses a 10 second timeout.  It was taking longer than 10 seconds to parse the DASH manifest.  I hacked the parsing code in the DASH player to speed things up.  Now my video plays, but it would have been nice to be able to set my own timeout rather than relying on a hidden constant.