# How does Chromecast determine inactivity?

Tags: timeout, chromecast, google-cast

I've made a Chromecast app that displays multiple quotes and the whole idea is to basically connect it to a spare tv/monitor you have lying around and use it to have inspirational quotes change on the screen.

But the problem is, Chromecast automatically times out and goes back to the home screen after every few minutes of inactivity. I'd like to find out how it detects inactivity so I can prevent this behavior and allow my app to keep running on the Chromecast indefinitely, as a sort of replacement for the original photo screensaver.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out how to keep my app running.  There is a property of `CastReceiverOptions` called [`disableIdleTimeout`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions#disableIdleTimeout) that can be set.

```
const options = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();
options.disableIdleTimeout = true;

const instance = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
instance.start(options);
```

With this set to `true`, the receiver no longer times out after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [`setInactivityTimeout`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#setInactivityTimeout) method then use the `maxInactivity` parameter which is interval in seconds before closing an unresponsive connection.

The `setInactivityTimeout(maxInactivity)` sets the receiver inactivity timeout. It is recommended to set the maximum inactivity value when calling Start and not changing it. This API is just provided for development/debugging purposes.

You may also refer with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783237/5832311) which stated that:

> Timeout value cannot be adjusted by application. It would help us to understand what is causing the timeout in your case. Timeout happens when either the sender does not reply to the receiver's ping requests in a timely manner, or when the sender has not received a ping from the receiver for a certain length of time. It might be the case that the media you are trying to load is tying up the CPU on the receiver so that it can't send its ping request to the sender.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apparently it doesn't care about maxInactivity.