# Chromecast times out during custom sender/receiver playback

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm developing a custom chromecast app, and one of the chromecast devices I'm testing with will timeout (or go to the screensaver for a different reason) exactly 5 minutes after casting no matter what I try.

*The sender still thinks it's connected, and audio playback persists, but the video switches to the default google cast image slideshow.*

I've tried every suggestions in both these other questions

- [Google Cast custom receiver timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673152/google-cast-custom-receiver-timing-out)
- [How does Chromecast determine inactivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621478/how-does-chromecast-determine-inactivity)

but nothing works.

In desperation, I switched the receiver ID to the default receiver and even that times out, **even during media playback**. Pressing play/pause/stop buttons periodically doesn't keep the receiver from timing out either. I don't think I can communicate how frustrating this has been.

The only thing I know that works is casting with a different app like youtube. The youtube app will stream for hours without timing out, so it's definitely something with my app, but at this point I don't even know what steps I could take to debug further.

Any information or help would be very appreciated.